# Where to insert redirect code based on http_referer?

Tags: php, redirect

If the client arrives at my WordPress site from a specific other domain, I want to direct the client to a specific page on my site. Preferably, I would like to use the PHP header function to perform the redirect, but non-coding solutions will be considered.

Right now I have placed conditional code at the very top of my active theme's header.php file, and if the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "some.domain.com"` then I perform the redirect using a common html meta refresh, like so:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "https://www.somewebsite.com/"){
    ?><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://my.wordpresssite.com/my-custom-page/"><?php
}
```

The PHP `header("Location: /my-custom-page/")` doesn't work there, presumably because content output has already occurred. Meta refresh does the job for now, but it is very crude. My main problem with using meta refresh is that even with "0" seconds, the page content is already starting to load before the client is redirected to the special page I really wanted them to be on in the first place. So a user gets to see the masthead and other parts of the homepage for a couple of seconds, then they are taken to the page I want them to be on.

WordPress executes many files and functions even before it loads header.php. I want to know where I can put a PHP header redirect to a relative page in my WordPress (assuming there is no feasible non-coding solution). I don't want to modify wp-admin or wp-include files, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) hook (in your `functions.php`):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function () {
    if ( wp_get_raw_referer() === 'https://www.somewebsite.com/' ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( 'my-custom-page/' ) );
        exit;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Great solution, which works, to an extent. Technically, I believe it is the correct solution. Only problem is now as it tries to redirect to the correct page, I now get : "The page isn’t redirecting properly An error occurred during a connection to (my.domain.com). This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies." This is the exact same issue I was getting when I tried to use a PHP header location in the header.php, which is why I abandoned it. Now, if I type the identical url into the address bar, the page loads correctly.

Comment: I marked this answer as correct, but in truth the wp_redirect is failing me by giving a "This page isn't redirecting properly" error. I replaced the wp_redirect with the javascript solution as found here: http://jafty.com/blog/wp_redirect-causing-page-isnt-redirecting-properly-error/ and it works perfectly for my needs.